# Catch click on input type "checkbox"

Tags: jquery

Is there any ways to catch click on input, only if type of input set to checkbox?
**Note:** I need to catch click without using any classes or id's.

I've tried following:

```
$('input').on('click', function(){   
    if($(this).attr('type','checkbox')){
           alert("checkbox clicked");
        }
});
```

Well, this is not working and I don't know any other ways.
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x8utn/

Comment: if($(this).attr('type') == 'checkbox')

Comment: You are using `attr` as setter which returns an object, a truthy value, you are not comparing.

Comment: +1 exactly what @undefined said! (I'm bad with words this time in the morning)

Comment: change to this: `if($(this).is(':checkbox')){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USe like this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x8utn/)

Or you can use like

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){ });
```

Answer (score 1):

your jquery would be

```
$('input:checkbox').on('click', function(){   

           alert("checkbox clicked");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/x8utn/3/)

Answer (score 0):

**Error in your code :**

`$(this).attr('type') == 'checkbox'` : get attribute and not `$(this).attr('type','checkbox')` : set attribute.

---

`$('input')` will bind click event to all input elements.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x8utn/1/)**

Use attribute selector `[attr="value"]`

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){..})
```

Or pseudo selector `:checkbox`

```
$(':checkbox').on('click', function(){   })
```

**Side Note** : Prefer using `change` event on input elements.

Answer (score 0):

your not using type attr in your if condition properly.
Also you can use this way  :

```
$('input').on('click', function(){ 
    if($('#check').is(":checked"))
        {
           alert("checkbox clicked");
        }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x8utn/2/